# Received memory warning while opening camera and taking photo in iphone 4s os 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7.1

I use just simple code for taking photo from the camera but when I open camera using below code I am getting **Received memory warning** and after taking photo, the application is getting crashed. is there any solution?

This issue occurs in iPhone4s and os 7.1.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES;

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: try imagepicker globly and use

Comment: @BhaveshNai what do you mean?

Comment: UIImagePickerController *imagePicker declare in .h file

Comment: if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES;

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: Hey @BhaveshNai - Still getting same issue.

Comment: I put below code in UIButton action event for taking Photo,if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES;

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: And ImagePickerController Delegate - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: try to realse your object in didreceivememorywarning method

Comment: imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES;
no need this line by default is yes..read documentation

Comment: I remove this imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES; line but still same getting issue.

Comment: I use this code in iPad 4 and os is 7.1, but not getting any kind of issue, why this happen in iPhone4s with os 7.1?

Answer (score 1):

The imagePicker itself is NOT the issue. Yes, it does use a lot of memory when taking a picture but that hardly be reduced.

You are wasting/using memory in other parts of your app.

There is no 'do it like this and it will work':

three things to do:
1. verify all your objects are indeed deallocated when no longer needed. (Id use instruments allocations tool)

1. see WHERE you use soooo much memory that the camera crashes. (can also be seen using instruments)
2. You should implement the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method in your VC and when the message comes, try to release as much memory as you can. (data that you can easily reload!)